Databricks custom keep alive cluster
I've upgraded my databricks cluster to 10.4 LTS to 12.2 LTS and I have a breaking change in the way we use the cluster.
For some context, we deploy python code on Azure Machine Learning VMs that will connect to Databricks clusters.
We have one cluster that we share between algorithms. So that all python runs can access to the same cluster and scale horizontally. It's usefull for multiple users and also lowering our costs.
To lower even more our costs, we decided to put the terminated after X minutes of inactivity option to 10 minutes. But some of our algorithm need the spark session to be kept alive for longer than 10 minutes. Most of the time we write the DF into a temp table or a file, and we load it up after. But sometimes it's best for us to keep the sesison opened to keep the DF alive.
For this we made a thread to ping every 9 minutes the cluster.
    if keep_alive:
        # Keep Spark alive in a separate thread
        self._keep_spark_alive_thread = threading.Thread(
            target=self._keep_spark_alive,
            daemon=True,
        )
        self._keep_spark_alive_thread.start()

    def _keep_spark_alive(self):
        """
        Keeps the Spark session alive by running a dummy job and sleeping for a specified interval.

        This method runs an infinite loop that periodically executes a dummy job on the Spark session
        to prevent it from being terminated due to inactivity. It sleeps for a specified interval between
        each execution of the dummy job.

        Returns:
            None
        """
        while True:
            # Run a dummy job to keep Spark alive
            try:
                logging.debug("Keeping Spark alive...")
                self._spark.sql(f"SELECT '{self.project_name}'").collect()

                # Sleep for 9 minutes
                # time.sleep(9 * 60)
                time.sleep(20) # 20 seconds for debug
            except Exception as e:
                logging.debug(f"Error keeping Spark alive: {e}")

Using this thread in a 10.4 LTS cluster, the spark sql is sent and kept the cluster alive.
But in 12.2 LTS, the spark sql is sent BUT it ignors is as an activity and if there's no other query/actions within 10 minutes, the cluster shutdowns.
I tryed to lower the sleep to 20 seconds, and here is was happend. Every 20 seconds I could see the activity in Spark Logs, but after 10 minutes, it started to shutdown. 10 minutes and 20 seconds, it starts up again because of the thread. But i lose the spark session since the cluster is restarted.
My debug logs:
Keeping Spark alive...
Keeping Spark alive...
24/09/30 13:54:05 WARN SparkServiceRPCClient: The cluster seems to be down. A
24/09/30 13:54:06 WARN SparkServiceRPCClient: Cluster xxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxxxx in
24/09/30 13:54:16 WARN SparkServiceRPCClient: Cluster xxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxxxx in
24/09/30 13:54:26 WARN SparkServiceRPCClient: Cluster xxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxxxx in
24/09/30 13:54:37 WARN SparkServiceRPCClient: Cluster xxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxxxx in
24/09/30 13:54:47 WARN SparkServiceRPCClient: Cluster xxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxxxx in
24/09/30 13:54:57 WARN SparkServiceRPCClient: Cluster xxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxxxx in
Error keeping Spark alive: requirement failed: Result for RPC Some(87d40863-d
Keeping Spark alive...
Keeping Spark alive...

Do you know why spark.sql(f"SELECT '{self.project_name}'").collect() is not working as an activity? Does the new version of pyspark knows that the query is the same, thus kept in cache somewhere?

What do you use to connect from AML to Databricks? Spark Connect?

You are trying to keep the cluster active by pinging every 9 minutes. Why not leave it running? Why terminate after 10 mins?

@phcaze we use SparkSession and the configuration of the cluster is in a local file. Our wrapper calls Databricks API to generate a PAT and setup the .databricks-connect file.
@GaneshChandrasekaran We dont want to leave it running because it costs lot of money and all our process does not take the same time to run and uses the same cluster. We do not want to setup multiple clusters, it's way too expensive et takes lot of time to start up.

To give an other example, some people might make some dev on a notebook, go to lunch, come back and see they lost all their spark session, so losing data + time => human money + machine money

Yes, it is possible that your query is cached and not considered as activity since you are running the same query every time it doesn't need to recompute it again.
Also, auto terminate check for spark job. If there is no spark job for 10 minutes, it automatically terminates.
So, create a simple notebook job in workflows and trigger it for every 9 minutes.
databricks_instance = "https://axyz..syx10.azuredatabricks.net"
access_token = "dapib....."
job_id = "142342612795035"


url = f"{databricks_instance}/api/2.1/jobs/run-now"

headers = {
    "Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
}
payload = {
    "job_id": job_id
}


def _keep_spark_alive():
    
    while True:
        try:
            logger.info("Keeping Spark alive...")
            response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(payload))
            if response.status_code == 200:
                print("Job triggered successfully.")
                print("Response:", response.json())
            else:
                print("Failed to trigger job.")
                print("Status Code:", response.status_code)
                print("Response:", response.text)
            time.sleep(60*3)
        except Exception as e:
            logging.info(f"Error keeping Spark alive: {e}")

Output:

Here, for every 3 minutes the job is triggered and keeping the cluster active.
Alternatively, you can run the python or sql command in your cluster for every 9 mins using the Command Execution API

Thank for the answer. I've been checking on my side and I think I've found a solution that requires less changes on my side and should be less consumming. I changed the "select 1" into a DF creation of a single data and write it into a tmp folder on ADLS.
